# group multiple field data as one field in sql

Tags: mysql, group-by

My sql query

```
select status,count(id) from table group by status;
```

returns following Data

```
Resolved- 4
Closed - 12
Verified - 3
New* - 23
Unconfirmed* - 4
Needmoreinfo* - 5.
```

What i want mysql to return is

```
Resolved- 4
Closed - 12
Verified - 3
Found* - 32
```

i.e New,Unconfirmed,Needmoreinfo should be counted as 'Found'

Comment: Provide some sample table data and explain the problem exactly.

Comment: select CASE WHEN status NOT IN ('Resolved','Closed','Verified') THEN 'FOUND' ELSE status END as derived_status,count(id) from table group by CASE WHEN status NOT IN ('Resolved','Closed','Verified') THEN 'FOUND' ELSE status END;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your question is missing information to help you.. but maybe you want this

```
SELECT 
CASE WHEN (status NOT IN ('Resolved', 'Closed', 'Verified')) THEN 'Found*' ELSE status END as status, count(id) 
FROM table 
GROUP BY CASE WHEN (status NOT IN ('Resolved', 'Closed', 'Verified')) THEN 'Found*' ELSE status END
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing is us nned to alter ur table i.e add one extra colum
      LTER TABLE yourtable ADD COLUMN Found VARCHAR(50);

UPDATE yourtable SET Found = CONCAT(New, ' - ', Unconfirmed, ', ', Needmoreinfo);

and now u can write select query